# Oracle SQL - create select statement which will retrieve every end date of the month but compare the values the day or two after the end of month

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a customer table.

```
customer_name ||   date  ||  amount
-----------------------------------
A               31-OCT-20    100
A               01-NOV-20    100
A               02-NOV-20    200
B               31-OCT-20    300
B               01-NOV-20    325
B               02-NOV-20    350
```

I need to create a select statement which will retrieve every end date of the month and compare the values for the amounts respective to the day or two after. If the amount for the day or two is different from the end date of that month, display the recent changed amount.

Example 1 - Retrieve customer A for 31-OCT-20, compare to 01-NOV-20 and 02-NOV-20, output 200 for the amount.

Example 2 - Retrieve customer B for 31-OCT-20, compare to 01-NOV-20 and 02-NOV-20, output 350 for the amount.

Comment: Will the **dates** always be consecutive? Or could you have 31-OCT-20 followed by 15-NOV-20 for a client (with no rows for 1-NOV, 2-NOV etc.)?

Comment: correct, if there are no rows for 1-NOV or 2-NOV then just display the original amount for 31-OCT

Comment: OK. What is your Oracle version? This can be done easily with `match_recognize` but that requires version 12.1 or higher. And, also, what if for example you have data (for a customer) for 28-OCT, but nothing for 29, 30, 31 OCT? Do you want to show the data for 28-OCT, or nothing at all for October? Or is that not even possible in your data?

Comment: You chose a "correct answer" that will give you the wrong answer if dates like 1-NOV are missing from your data. You did this after I asked you for clarification, and after I commented below that answer, pointing out that it will NOT handle that type of situation correctly. All I can say is, **BRILLIANT**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

```
select t.*,
       (case when next_amount <> amount or next2_amount <> amount
             then greatest(next_amount, next2_amount)
             else next_amount
        end) as imputed_next_2_days
from (select t.*,
             lead(amount) over (partition by customer_name order by date) as next_amount,
             lead(amount, 2) over (partition by customer_name order by date) as next2_amount
      from t
     ) t
where date = last_day(date);
```

Comment: Are you missing an argument of `2` in the second call to `lead()`?

Comment: Also, note my question to the OP and his reply. LEAD works on logical offsets (next row, next row after that) rather than physical offsets (one day, two days).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
Select * from
  (Select t.*, 
          row_number() over (partition by customer_name order by dt desc) as rn
     From your_table t
    Where extract(day from t.dt + 2) between 2 and 4)
Where rn = 1
```

Tip of the day: don't use oracle reserved keywords as the column name. (Date)